# Is it possible for regex to recognize whether a column is a string or an int?

Tags: regex

My goal is to split the string into groups. The problem is the current regex fails to recognize the part correctly.

The regex:

```
^(?: {2,})?(?P<TANGGAL>[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}){0,1}(?: {2,})?(?P<KETERANGAN1>[\w-/:]+(?: [\w-/:]+)*){0,1}(?: {2,})?(?P<KETERANGAN2>[\w-/:]+(?: [\w-/:]+)*){0,1}(?: {2})?(?P<SALDO>[\d,.]+){0,1}
```

The string:

```
      01/07          SALDO AWAL                                                                                                                       1,000.00
```

The problem:
The regex captures:

1. `1` from the string `1,000.00` as Group `KETERANGAN2` instead of Group `SALDO`.
2. `,000.00` as Group `SALDO` instead of capturing the whole `1,000.00`.

Comment: There are a lot of optional parts, what do you want to accomplish? Are there mandatory columns, like the first and the second?

Comment: Always tag your question with the tool/programming language you use. Regex is very different.

Comment: `[\w-/:]` looks invalid. That hyphen should be escaped or put at either end. `{0,1}` can just be `?`

Comment: A `\w` matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. so it matches a number too.

Comment: @Thefourthbird that's the problem. I want to group the line into each columns, namely `TANGGAL, KETERANGAN1,KETERANGAN2,CBG, MUTASI,SALDO`. However, there are no mandatory columns. I am converting a pdf to csv. The pdf table use multi whitespace to give illusion of a column.

Comment: @PoulBak the tool I use is regex101.com and the programming language is golang.

Comment: @PoulBak I am aware of `\w` to equal `a-zA-Z0-9`. However, the group `KETERANGAN2` also contains number, so I use `\w`. I am starting to think regex is not the right solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change optional capturing groups into obligatory and move them into the optional non-capturing groups that match the column delimiters:

```
^(?: {2,}(?P<TANGGAL>[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}))?(?: {2,}(?P<KETERANGAN1>[\w/:-]+(?: [\w/:-]+)*))?(?: {2,}(?P<KETERANGAN2>[\w/:-]+(?: [\w/:-]+)*))?(?: {2,}(?P<SALDO>[\d,.]+))?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/43gkTb/1).

Note the added `$` end of string anchor, it is necessary to make sure the whole line is matched.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?: {2,}(?P<TANGGAL>[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}))?` - an optional non-capturing group matching two or more spaces and then capturing into Group "TANGGAL" two digits, `/`, two digits
- `(?: {2,}(?P<KETERANGAN1>[\w/:-]+(?: [\w/:-]+)*))?` - an optional non-capturing group matching two or more spaces and then capturing into Group "KETERANGAN1" one or more word, `/`, `:` or `-` chars and then zero or more sequences of a space and then one or more word, `/`, `:`, `-` chars
- `(?: {2,}(?P<KETERANGAN2>[\w/:-]+(?: [\w/:-]+)*))?` - an optional non-capturing group matching two or more spaces and then capturing into Group "KETERANGAN2" one or more word, `/`, `:` or `-` chars and then zero or more sequences of a space and then one or more word, `/`, `:`, `-` chars
- `(?: {2,}(?P<SALDO>[\d,.]+))?` - an optional non-capturing group matching two or more spaces and then capturing into Group "SALDO" one or more digits, `,` or `.` chars
- `$` - end of string.